# Magento redirected to other URL after order editting

Tags: magento, redirect

Currently I'm experiencing a problem after editing orders in the Magento admin. The page is always redirected to another URL, the base of which belongs to the store view that the order belongs to. And this page requires re-login to the admin.

For example, I have two base URLs, each belongs to one store view:

```
www.example.old.com //old store view (default)
www.example.new.com //new store view
```

The system uses `www.example.old.com` as the default base URL. So under `www.example.old.com` I create an order for the new store and invoice it. Then on submitting the invoice, the page is redirected from

```
http://www.example.old.com/index.php/admin/sales_order_invoice/new/order_id/1234/
```

to

```
http://www.example.new.com/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/1234/
```

And it requires login for another time.

I traced the redirection code to `Mage_Core_Model_Url`

```
public function getRouteUrl($routePath=null, $routeParams=null)
    ...
    $url = $this->getBaseUrl().$this->getRoutePath($routeParams);

public function getBaseUrl($params = array())
    ....
    if (isset($params['_store'])) {
        $this->setStore($params['_store']);
    }
    ....
    return $this->getStore()->getBaseUrl($this->getType(), $this->getSecure());
```

Then I don't know what to do. There is no parameter `_store` but it seems that Magento determines which store view to run based on the order being treated, when it is supposed to stay on the same base URL throughout the admin.

Comment: What version of Magento is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may still show interests to this old entry, I share my solution. It is not a good one, indeed it is a hard-coded redirection to avoid going back to an uncertain URL, but it fixed the problem for me.

In the controller action where the redirection happens, modify

```
$this->_redirect(..., array(... => ...));
```

to

```
$this->_redirect(..., array(... => ..., '_store' => Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)));
```

This ensures that the redirection always goes to the specified store.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enable customer data sharing between the stores in the backend? 
Sorry for newbie answer, still learning magento

Comment: Thanks, Zippp. Actually it is turned on from the beginning. Have fun with Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is that Magento switchs context to store of order because it requires to translate the email template correctly.

Look at class Mage_Core_Model_Template there are two method _applyDesignConfig and _cancelDesignConfig. First function switches context and remember old context, second function should return all back. But, there is a bug. See more at: http://www.magthemes.com/magento-blog/magento-142-multiwebsite-admin-redirect-problem-quick-workaround/#comment-1084